# How to show directly that this sequence is Cauchy

Tags: real-analysis

I have been trying to prove that the sequence ${s_n}$ of real numbers given by

$$
{s_n=(1+\frac{1}{n})^n}
$$

is a Cauchy sequence. I know that this sequence converges to the real number $e$ and so it is a Cauchy sequence, but I want to prove it directly. Here is an image of what I have done so far:[image]

I am stuck in here because I don't know how to bound the last expression. I want some hints, NOT answers. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: It doesn't work. $m^n$'s are too big to be small as we want!

Comment: Unfortunately, you're doomed at the very first inequality you write, since both of the terms in that sum on the right going to be at least 1. You'll have to find some cancellation, which means expanding the binomials, as ugly as that sounds.

Comment: @hunter you say, using the binomial theorem?

Comment: This sequence is typically the prototype for demonstrating the Monotone convergence theorem. It's pretty easy to show it's monotonic with the AMGM and only a slight nuisance to show it's bounded. It's fairly hard to show it's Cauchy without an approach that would demonstrate convergence through another route.

Comment: $s_n$ is strictly increasing,so the first inequality may be unnecessary.